# Is there any simulator that can receive calls and decode DTMF tones?

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio programmable voice to make the outgoing calls to one of my device.

As part of handshake, we have to exchange few DTMF tones between twilio and device.

But due to unavailability of device every time i am not able to test the calls and see what DTMF tones are being exchanged.

So here i am looking for some kind of simulator which is capable of receiving phone calls and display the DTMF tones received.

I am using my mobile phone to receive calls but i am not able to decode the DTMF tones.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set up that logic on another Twilio phone number that answers with a [Gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) and reads back the `Digits` result with a [Play](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play). You can do this using Twilio Studio with the [Gather Input on Call Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/gather-input-call) and the `Say/Play Widget` or the [HTTP Request Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request) which posts the resulting `Digits` to a webhook of yours, to easily tabulate the responses.